# Exponential moments of expected return time in an irreducible Markov chain.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $\left( X_n\right)_{n\geqslant0}$ be a Markov chain on a finite set $E$. For all $x\in E$, we define the return time to $x$ by
$$\tau_x=\inf\left\{n\geqslant1\colon X_n=x\mid X_0=x\right\}.$$

If the chain is irreducible, we know that for any $x\in E$, we have $\mathbb{E}_x\left[\tau_x\right]<\infty$.

Show that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $$\mathbb{E}_x\left[\exp\left(\varepsilon\tau_x\right)\right]<+\infty$$

Deduce that for all $p\geqslant1$, $$\mathbb{E}_x\left[\left(\tau_x\right)^p\right]<+\infty$$

The second part is easy if we have the first part, but I do not know how to get this one...

Any hints ?

Comment: Presumably the intent of this exercise is to use the first result to prove the second. How did you arrive at the first result, and how is it related to the second?

Comment: @Math1000 As I wrote, having the second part from the first part is easy by expanding the exponential into its power sum. It is the first part that I do not get, and I do not know how to get it. That is why I like to ha ve some hints !

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about "expanding the exponential into its power sum."

Comment: @Math1000 I do not know what you are getting at... I want hints for the first part, not the second. If I can show the first part, then for any $p\geqslant 1$, we have $$E\left(\frac{\varepsilon^p\tau_x^p}{p!}\right)\leqslant E\left(\exp\left(\varepsilon\tau_x\right)\right)<+\infty$$ which yields the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: (i) Let $p_{n} = Prob\{\tau_{x} = n\}$. Then $E \exp(\epsilon \tau_{x}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_{n} \exp(\epsilon n)$.

(ii) $\exp(\epsilon n) = [\exp(\epsilon)]^{n}$.

(iii) $\exp(\epsilon) > 1$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

The rest depends on what you have learned about $p_{n}$.